# optimized way to check if table is empty SQLite

Tags: java, android, sqlite, count, android-sqlite

I am working over a project that in which the database has multiple tables. Some of these tables are empty and some contain a few million rows. I need to check if a table is empty. This is the piece of code(extracted needed part):

```
private boolean isEmpty(Uri uri){
   ContentResolver cr = getContext().getContentResolver();
   Cursor cursor = cr.query(uri, new String[]{COUNT(_id)}, null, null, null);
   if(cursor.moveToFirst())
     return cursor.getInt(0) == 0;
   return true;
}
```

However since some of the files contain a lot of rows, count(_id) takes huge amount of time,and results into time out. Is there another way in SQLite to optimize this process?

P.S: _id is the primary key of for the tables, so cant be null.

Comment: The query is fine; there might be a lot of overhead from your ContentResolver implementation.

Comment: @laalto you mean count(_id) for a million rows wont affect the performance?
or overhead from ContentResolver implementation will be much higher as compared to it?
I read over multiple pages that normal SQL statement can be used for this: 
Select 1 from table LIMIT 1 
But how can this be implemented in here?

Comment: Aggregate function such as count() only returns one row, so limiting the result set to one row has no practical effect.

Comment: count will go through all of the _ids, meaning traverse the whole table, I do not require that. My work will be done if I can confirm there exist at least 1 row.
select 1 from table will return the constant 1 for every row of the table.

Comment: IIRC counting on an indexed column should be faster than a full table scan and a primary key is indexed. You can also try `COUNT(*)` to see if it is any better for you.

Answer (score 0):

If you can use a `SQLiteOpenHelper` class in conjuction with your `ContentResolver` to execute `rawQuery()`, then a simple way to get a result of `1` (the table contains rows) or `0` (the table is empty), is the use of `EXISTS`:

```
SELECT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM tablename) AS result
```

In this case, if the table is not empty, `EXISTS` will stop and return a value of `1` as soon as it finds the 1st row.

Comment: Although I understand the concept you explained above, but usage of SQLiteOpenHelper would require to do a few more changes in my rest of code.